# Visitor design pattern intent : misleading or I am missing something?

Tags: java, design-patterns, extensibility, visitor-pattern

in the reference book "Design Patterns Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" by the gang of four, the intent of the visitor pattern is explained as follow :

> Represent an operation to be performed on the elements of an object structure. Visitor lets you define a new operation without changing the classes of the elements on which it operates.

Another advantage I read about the visitor pattern is that:

> ADD A NEW OPERATION **WITHOUT HAVING THE SOURCE CODE** OF THE CLASSES..

I made a deep search in Google, but I did not find any example showing how to do that.
So let's take a simple example :

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void myMethod();
}

public class MyClassA implements MyInterface {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.mycomp.tutorials.designpattern.behavorials.MyInterface#myMethodA()
     */
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("myMethodA implemented in MyClassA");

    }

}

public class MyClassB implements MyInterface {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.mycomp.tutorials.designpattern.behavorials.MyInterface#myMethodA()
     */
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("myMethod implemented in MyClassB");

    }

}
```

So how would I add a new method `myNewMethod()` to this hierarchy of classes without changing them, using the visitor pattern?

Comment: I think your interface should have a method that accepts a visitor at all. Your classes should be aware that there could be a visitor which changes the behaviour. The visitor design pattern is not a magic bullet where you just can change a behavior from outside.

Comment: You cannot. You need to change those classes to have an accept method. You can add new operations to classes where you don't have the source code... provided the classes have already been compiled with an accept method in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a Message class, and 2 subclasses Email and Sms.

You could have many operations on these two classes, like `sendToOnePerson()`, `sendToSeveralPeople()`. But you probably don't want to have these methods in the Email and Sms class directly, because it tightly couples them to the SMTP/phone system. And you would also like to be able to add other operations in the futre, like forward() or delete(), or whatever. So the first implementation you could use is

```
public void delete(Message message) {
    if (message instanceof Email) {
        deleteEmail(Email) message);
    }
    else if (message instanceof Sms) {
        deleteSms((Sms) message);
    }
}
```

But this is ugly: it's not object-oriented, and it will fail if there is a new VoiceMessage subclass appearing.

An alternative is to use the visitor pattern.

```
public interface MessageVisitor {
    void visitEmail(Email email);
    void visitSms(Sms sms);
}

public abstract class Message {
    public void accept(MessageVisitor visitor);
}

public class Email extends Message {
    @Override
    public void accept(MessageVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitEmail(this);
    }
}

public class Sms extends Message {
    @Override
    public void accept(MessageVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitSms(this);
    }
}
```

This way, to implement send(), all you need is a MessageVisitor implementation that can send an email and send an Sms:

```
SendMessageVisitor visitor = new SendMessageVisitor();
message.accept(visitor);
```

And if you introduce a new delete() operation, you don't have to touch to Message classes at all. All you need is a DeleteMessageVisitor:

```
DeleteMessageVisitor visitor = new DeleteMessageVisitor();
message.accept(visitor);
```

So, basically, it's a bit like if you added polymorphic methods to the Message classes by not actually modifying the Message classes.

Comment: your example is very clear. Thanks. Let's use it as the base. But suppose you are not the designer of the element classes (Message,Email, Sms), and you don't have access to the source code of element classes. Will you still be able to use visitor design pattern, to "add method to the message class library"? How would you do that?

Comment: No, you won't. This must be a design decision

Answer (score 2):

You example is **not** a visitor pattern. It is just inheritance.

A visitor pattern first requires an visitor `interface`

```
interface ThingVisitor {
    void visit(ThingA a);
    void visit(ThingB b);
}
```

Now you need an `interface Thing`:

```
interface Thing {
    void accept(ThingVisitor visitor);
}
```

And your implementation of, for example, `ThingA` would be

```
class ThingA implements Thing {
    public void accept(final ThingVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Now you see the logic to handle the `Thing` types is contained in the implementations of `ThingVisitor`.

Answer (score 0):

The visitor pattern assumes that you have a method in the classes you want to "visit" which accepts and executes the visitor, here is an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). The pattern is not motivated by adding functionality to foreign classes but to localize functionality in the visitors which would otherwise be spread over several classes, e.g. for saving elements (see the example).

Answer (score 0):

**Quick description of the visitor pattern.**

The classes that require modification must all implement the 'accept' method. Clients call this accept  method to perform some new action on that family of classes thereby extending their functionality. Clients are able to use this one accept method to perform a wide range of new actions by passing in a different visitor class for each specific action. A visitor class contains multiple  overridden visit methods defining how to achieve that same specific action for every class within the family. These visit methods get passed an instance on which to work